# readObject() throws EOFException although no data is written yet

Tags: java, sockets, eof, objectinputstream, objectoutputstream

I'm currently writing a client-server application where data should be transferred to the server to process the data. For building the connection I use ServerSocket and Socket and for sending the data I use OutputStream + ObjectOutputStream on the client-side and InputStream + ObjectInputStream on the server-side. The connection is currently running on localhost.

The object I try to transfer is a serializable class that only contains String parameters.

The problem I'm facing now is that readObject() immediately throws an EOFException as soon as the OutputStreams of the client are initialized (which leads to an initialization of the InputStreams of the server at the same time) instead of waiting for input from the client.

I send the data from the client using this code:

```
    public void send(DataSet dataSet) {
        if (!clientStreamsEstablished) {
            initiateClientStreams();
        }
        try {
            out.writeObject(dataSet);
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
```

This method is only called when I hit the "submit"-button in the UI so it will not be executed on start of the application.

The data is currently (already tried a ton of other approaches with and without while() loop etc., etc.) read on the server using this method:

```
    private void waitForInput(ObjectInputStream in, InputStream listeningPort) {
        boolean dataReceived = false;
        DataSet dataSet = null;

        System.out.println("waiting ...");
        while (!dataReceived) {
            try {
                Object temp = in.readObject(); // <-- EOFException is thrown here
                boolean test = false;
                if (temp instanceof DataSet) {
                    dataSet = (DataSet) temp;
                }
            } catch (ClassNotFoundException | IOException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
                break;
            }
        }

        System.out.println("Test 2: " + dataSet.toString());

        if (dataReceived) {
            waitForInput(in, listeningPort);
        }
    }
```

As soon as the client thread on the server reaches this line (see code-comment above) I get this stacktrace:

```
java.io.EOFException
    at java.io.ObjectInputStream$BlockDataInputStream.peekByte(ObjectInputStream.java:2626)
    at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readObject0(ObjectInputStream.java:1321)
    at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readObject(ObjectInputStream.java:373)
    at com.labdashboardserver.ClientThread.waitForInput(ClientThread.java:53)
    at com.labdashboardserver.ClientThread.run(ClientThread.java:43)
Exception in thread "Thread-2" java.lang.NullPointerException
    at com.labdashboardserver.ClientThread.waitForInput(ClientThread.java:65)
    at com.labdashboardserver.ClientThread.run(ClientThread.java:43)
```

The reason for the second part of the stacktrace containing the NullPointerException is apparent as due to the EOFExcpetion the dataSet never is initialized.

However from my point of view readObject() should block and wait for the client to send ANY data before starting to read it and throw an EOF. I feel like I read through half of Stack Overflow and other forums searching for an answer but the articles I found only discuss reading files or only immediate temporary streams which are closed afterwards.

### Edit

I initialize the connection before calling the UI in my main method:

```
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        connector = new LabConnector();
        connector.run();
        if (connector.getConnectionEstablished()) {
            EventQueue.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
                public void run() {
                    try {
                        frame = new LabUI();
                        frame.setVisible(true);
                    } catch (Exception e) {
                        JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null,
                                "Error Message:\n" + e.getMessage() + "\nProgram shutting down!", "Critical Error", 0);
                    }
                }
            });
    }
```

While in the LabConnector class I initialize the streams and connection like this:

```
    public void run() {
        try {
            establishConnection();
        } catch (UnknownHostException e) {
            retryConnection(e);
        } catch (IOException e) {
            retryConnection(e);
        }

        if (connectionEstablished) {
            initiateClientStreams();
        }

    }

    private void establishConnection() throws UnknownHostException, IOException {

        client = new Socket(HOST_IP_ADRESS, HOST_PORT);

        JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Connected to Server!");

        connectionEstablished = true;

    }

    private void initiateClientStreams() {
        try {
            sendingPort = client.getOutputStream();
            out = new ObjectOutputStream(sendingPort);
            clientStreamsEstablished = true;
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
```

Comment: You are trying to read an object twice, but are only only sending it once?  Try checking in.available().

Comment: @SteveSmith I'm not entirely sure what you exactly mean as the only .write() command on the client side is in the send-method noted in my post, but I'll append some more code of the class building the connection in case that helps.

Comment: @SteveSmith good suggestion! It works now when putting the readObject() in the following condition: if(in.available >= 0) { /*readObject()-call*/ }

Comment: The `EOFException` occurs because the peer has closed the connection. Using `available()` won't fix that, or anything else either, and as it never returns -1 testing it for >= 0 accomplishes exactly diddly-squat. Check the sending code.

Comment: @user207421 is right. The client probably dies before it sends anything to wire. It should flush, shutdownOutput() and only then close

Comment: @user207421 You are right, I accidently commented out a line of code that was meant to close the connection in case I close my client application and due to this the program worked fine again. Have to check again on how to implement this functionality properly so the connection doesn't get reset right at the start of the application.

Comment: @basin `flush()` before `close()` is redundant, and `shutdownOutput()` before `close()` ditto. The problem is the close itself, or the failure to send anything first, or maybe this code's failure to deal with the case of empty input.